# Accessing Elements of a Deeply Nested Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, nested

I'm attempting to access nested elements of keys within my dictionary but getting hung up at every attempt to iterate through them.

I've attempted to flatten the dictionary and attempted various indexed accessors to the elements, but no luck.

Goal: Access the individual Elements such as:

```
print(flat['_items'][0]['items']['timestamp'])
print(flat['_items'][0]['items']['value'])
```

Below is the code used, the data and the element(s) I am trying to access.

```
def flatten_dict(dd, separator='_', prefix=''):
    return { prefix + separator + k if prefix else k : v
             for kk, vv in dd.items()
             for k, v in flatten_dict(vv, separator, kk).items()
             } if isinstance(dd, dict) else { prefix : dd }  

# Attempt to Flatten the Dictinary
flat = flatten_dict(regDataDict)

for k in flat.keys():
    print(k)   
    
for k, v in flat.items():
    print(k, v)

print(flat['_items'][0]['items']['timestamp']) # TypeError: string indices must be integers
print(flat['_items'][0]) # Prints all Dictionary Keys and Values
print(flat['_items']) # Prints all Dictionary Keys and Values
print(flat['_items']['{items}']) # TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The Dictionary Structure

```
_items = [
    {'items': [{'errors': None,
                'good': True,
                'questionable': False,
                'substituted': False,
                'timestamp': '2021-02-01T21:40:00Z',
                'value': -180.625427,
                'web_exception': None}],
     'links': {'source': 'https://I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw8PMMAA'},
     'web_id': 'I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw8PMMAA'},
    {'items': [{'errors': None,
                'good': True,
                'questionable': False,
                'substituted': False,
                'timestamp': '2021-02-01T21:40:00Z',
                'value': 59.99268,
                'web_exception': None}],
     'links': {'source': 'https://I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw7_MMAA'},
     'web_id': 'I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw7_MMAA'},
    {'items': [{'errors': None,
                'good': True,
                'questionable': False,
                'substituted': False,
                'timestamp': '2021-02-01T21:39:56.055191Z',
                'value': 304.8489,
                'web_exception': None}],
     'links': {'source': 'https://I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegwuMYIAA'},
     'web_id': 'I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegwuMYIAA'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that your indexing doesn't match your structure.  `items` is a list containing a dict, not a dict itself.  The proper access sequence is

```
print(regDataDict[0]['items'][0]['timestamp'])
```

Which prints

```
2021-02-01T21:40:00Z
```

---

The long-term problem is that you *say* you're trying to flatten your dict, but:

1. It looks like you're still trying to access the result as if it were the original structure;
2. Your "flatten" routine merely slaps an empty-string key on the entire original value: you *add* a level, rather than flattening.

If you need to flatten the structure for some reason, then we need you to specify the resulting data structure, and trace your code to the problem point.

In particular, I observe that you have a habit of enclosing a dict as the only element of a list.  This seems to provide no organizational benefit.  If nothing else, your data cleansing should probably get rid of this extra level.

Comment: Prune, this is helpful, however it only works if I strip off the " _items" string that precedes the [ ] structure in my dictionary. For every other combination of indexes and strings, I get the same error. I will give you credit for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks also to blorgon for suggesting a restructuring of the data. Unfortunately the data is from an API service for which I have no control of the output.

Answer (score 0):

OP, as a supplement to Prune's answer, might I suggest an alternate structure for your data where the `web_id` becomes the key and the associated data is an inner dictionary:

```py
_items = {
    'I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw8PMMAA': {
        'errors': None,
        'good': True,
        'questionable': False,
        'substituted': False,
        'timestamp': '2021-02-01T21:40:00Z',
        'value': -180.625427,
        'web_exception': None,
        'source': 'https://I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw8PMMAA'
    },
    'I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw7_MMAA': {
        'errors': None,
        'good': True,
        'questionable': False,
        'substituted': False,
        'timestamp': '2021-02-01T21:40:00Z',
        'value': 59.99268,
        'web_exception': None,
        'source': 'https://I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegw7_MMAA'
    },
    'I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegwuMYIAA': {
        'errors': None,
        'good': True,
        'questionable': False,
        'substituted': False,
        'timestamp': '2021-02-01T21:40:00Z',
        'value': 304.8489,
        'web_exception': None,
        'source': 'https://I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMegwuMYIAA'
    }
}
```

I don't really know what you're working on, and I'm assuming `web_id` is unique for each object (otherwise, using `_id` is very misleading!), I just thought I'd throw this out there as it'd be a lot easier to work with.

Here's how you could do the data cleaning, assuming your input data's structure is consistent:

```py
new_items = {}
for d in _items:
    new_items[d['web_id']] = {**d['items'][0]}
    new_items[d['web_id']]['source'] = d['links']['source']
```

You could also strip the common substring from the `web_id` if you want cleaner keys:

```py
new_items = {}
for d in _items:
    new_id = d['web_id'].replace('I1DPOGpIXSBWLkGcEkjIvyMeg', '')
    new_items[new_id] = {**d['items'][0]}
    new_items[new_id]['source'] = d['links']['source']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone,

I modified my approach to something that feels much more OO and avoids a lot of unnessary dictionary and list manipulation.

1. Convert the original object to a Dictionary.
2. Convert the dictionary to a Class.
3. Access the Class members in standard OO fashion.

I borrowed the Class structure from Kien Nguyen Trung's awesome post here: https://kiennt.com/blog/2012/06/14/python-object-and-dictionary-convertion.html

```
class PiStruct(object):
      def __init__(self, **entries):
            self.__dict__.update(entries)

# convert to PI Response "Class" to Dictionary 
regDataDict = piItemsStreamValuesR.__dict__

# convert the Dictionary to a Class
classMembers = PiStruct(**regDataDict)

# Print the Class Members
for i in range(0,len(classMembers._items)): 
    for n in range(0,len(classMembers._items[i].items)):
        print('Timestamp:', classMembers._items[i].items[i].timestamp)
        print('Reading:', classMembers._items[i].items[i].value)
        print('Name:', classMembers._items[i].name)
```

Original PI Object Type: <class 'osisoft.pidevclub.piwebapi.models.pi_items_stream_values.PIItemsStreamValues'>

```
Timestamp: 2021-02-02T16:42:00Z
Reading: 145.6539
Name: Sample Name
Timestamp: 2021-02-02T16:42:00Z
Reading: 59.9942245
Name: Sample Name
Timestamp: 2021-02-02T16:41:20.4717254Z
Reading: -189.0652
Name: Sample Name
```